# Why placeholders in MS teams don't work in simple custom url tab?

Tags: php, microsoft-teams

I try to implement already build app in PHP to Teams custom tab. Page works fine but I need some data from teams. All data I need are provided in placeholders as noted here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context

The problem is that if I insert any placeholder like ?tid={tid} I get a blank page. I can't find a way to debug this to find what's wrong.

Basically I have a simple PHP applications where I need to read $_GET data but for some reason when I add any placeholder temas displays a blank tab.

I just need to check $_GET['tid'] in my app to get {tid} value from teams.

Comment: Please show us some code and read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: My app is hosted on some domain https://myapp.com where for test I only have index.php where os only <?php echo '<pre>'.print_r($_GET,true).'</pre>'; ?>
If I put https://myapp.com?tid=test in teams tab it shows: Array(tid=> test)
If I put https://myapp.com?tid={tid} tab doesn't display any page.

Comment: Are you able to access the files tab?

Comment: Yes, all works fine except that custom tab with url containing {...}

Comment: Could you please share your app manifest so we can look into issue further?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to post the app manifest somewhere, so we can see exactly what it looks like to help troubleshoot? Perhaps paste the json here, or upload it somewhere we can access. I assume you're using [App Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/app-studio-overview)? If so, it has an option to export (download) a copy of this manifest.

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end?

Comment: I don't use any json manifest because I'm not building an app. I just want to display simple webpage inside tab + get some data from URL. Classic page works fine, placeholders {tid} break the site

Comment: Ahh, ok, now I understand. To my knowledge, that won't work at all - those tokens are -only- applicable to an actual Teams app, most likely for security reasons (an uninformed user could unwittingly have information stolen by a rogue web page). You'd need to "upgrade" your site to that it's a full-blown Teams app (not really that much work, just use the App Studio I mentioned and create a "Tab" app).

Comment: (ran out of space, continuing here) Another option is to sign the user in on your site, and get the information from the Graph, basically, inside your web site. That would work nicely then if they're in a tab OR if they open it out as a full page.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Docs about it are unclear because I was following instructions how to create a custom tab with page in it + get some data from channel. All links lead to example I tried and nowhere is mentioned that is for MS app only or something similar. I don't see any problem with "rouge sites" stealing my data because I define in teams what site is displayed in tab so it's impossible for someone to hijack any data. Anyway thanx for suggestion, I'll try to use App Studio for it. However MS teams could give us an error or something and not a blank page when I use a parameter.

Comment: yeah, I also wish it showed something better than just a blank page!